# How to display an element on hover over other element

Tags: html, css, button, hover

I want to display a button element on hovering another button element but my code doesn't work.

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="right-account">
  <button class="btn_login">MY ACCOUNT</button>
    <a href="../products/user_cart.php"><button class="btn_signup">MY CART</button></a><br>
    <button class="pwd_button">Change Password</button>
</div>
```

**CSS Code**

```
.pwd_button{
display: none;
border: 1px solid #13619f;
background: #2371b7;
padding: 5px;
color: white;
font-size: 15px;
}

.btn_login:hover + .pwd_button{
display: block;
}
```

But this code is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try ti use [~](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/understanding-use-of-the-and-symbols-in-css-selectors-95552eb436f5):

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn_login')
const pwd = document.querySelector('.pwd_button')
btn.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  pwd.classList.add('showpwd')
})
pwd.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  pwd.classList.remove('showpwd')
})
```

```css
.pwd_button{
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid #13619f;
  background: #2371b7;
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.btn_login:hover ~ .pwd_button{
  display: block;
}
.showpwd {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="right-account">
  <button class="btn_login">MY ACCOUNT</button>
  <a href="../products/user_cart.php">
    <button class="btn_signup">MY CART</button>
  </a>
  <br>
  <button class="pwd_button">Change Password</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked. But when I move mouse little down from MY ACCOUNT Button, Change Password disappears. How can I make it visible ?

Comment: When I hover over MY ACCOUNT, Change Password appears but when I can't move my mouse to Change Password as it disappears as soon as I move mouse away from MY ACCOUNT. So, I want to click on Change Password Button but I can't.

Comment: You can do that with JavaScript, i updated answer, take a look pls

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the + combinator selects the immediate sibling and the password button is not the immediate sibling. But it is a sibling so you can do what you want by selecting with the tilda ~

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Combinators):

> General sibling combinator
> If you want to select siblings of an element even if they are not
> directly adjacent, then you can use the general sibling combinator
> (~).

So use:

```
.btn_login:hover ~ .pwd_button{
  display: block;
}
```

```css
.pwd_button {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid #13619f;
  background: #2371b7;
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.btn_login:hover~.pwd_button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="right-account">
  <button class="btn_login">MY ACCOUNT</button>

  <a href="../products/user_cart.php"><button class="btn_signup">MY CART</button></a><br>

  <button class="pwd_button">Change Password</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or we could do in this alternative way :-D :-P =>

```css
.pwd_button{
display: none;
border: 1px solid #13619f;
background: #2371b7;
padding: 5px;
color: white;
font-size: 15px;

}

.btn_login:hover + .pwd_button{
/*display: inline-block;*/
display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="right-account">
        <button class="btn_login">MY ACCOUNT</button>
        <button class="pwd_button">Change Password</button>
        <a href="../products/user_cart.php"><button class="btn_signup">MY CART</button></a><br>
</div>
```